# Format decimal places for primefaces ext input numeric

Tags: jsf, input, primefaces, numeric, primefaces-extensions

I have some code as below (work fine)

```
  <pe:inputNumber
        value="#{myBean.myVal}"
        minValue="0" maxValue="999999999999999.999999999"
        emptyValue="1"
        thousandSeparator="."
        decimalSeparator=","
    />
```

then, if i enter [1] it will show [1,000000000], my trouble is alot of zero maybe confuse my user. 
**Is there anyway to trim it on this input ?**, just display whatever user entered such as `[1,20] -> [1,2] or [1,20]`

Answer (score 2):

my script :

```
function trimDecimalPlace(){                
                var curVal = $(".ui-inputNum > input:first-child").val();
                var parseVal = '';
                if(curVal.indexOf(".") > curVal.indexOf(",")){
                    var tokens = curVal.split(".");
                    var decimalVal = parseFloat("0."+tokens[1])+"";                 
                    if(decimalVal != "0"){
                       parseVal = tokens[0]+"."+decimalVal.substring(2);
                    }else{
                       parseVal = tokens[0];
                    }   
                }else{
                    var tokens = curVal.split(",");
                    var decimalVal = parseFloat("0."+tokens[1])+"";                 
                    if(decimalVal != "0"){
                       parseVal = tokens[0]+","+decimalVal.substring(2);
                    }else{
                       parseVal = tokens[0];
                    }
                }
                $(".ui-inputNum > input:first-child").val(parseVal);
            }
```

and call it on blur:

```
    <pe:inputNumber
        value="#{myBean.myVal}"
        minValue="0" maxValue="999999999999999.999999999"
        emptyValue="1"
        onblur="trimDecimalPlace();"
        thousandSeparator="."
        decimalSeparator=","
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `decimalPlaces` attribute. The default value is obtained from the `maxValue` attribute, so in your case it is 999999999999999.**999999999**.

Comment: i had tried, but when set decimalPlaces='2' i can only enter *.99 as max

Comment: I used javascript to trim it to exactly result that user entered, not a best idea, but work fine.

Comment: May I ask why do you need to trim what the user entered instead of limiting the decimal numbers?

Comment: I allow my users to enter 0.999999999, not 0.99, however, I don't want 0.99 is display as 0.990000000

Answer (score 0):

Just use the tag padControl="false" with the inputNumber control

```
<p:inputNumber style="width:140px;"
    value="#{mopEdicionBean.permisoMop.mopKlmtFinalB}"
    thousandSeparator="" decimalPlaces="3" maxlength="4" minValue="0"
    maxValue="9999" size="16" padControl="false">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="nombre_permiso"/>
</p:inputNumber>
```